# jQuery .closest failed to find parent's input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML structure :

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity" value="1" min="1" max="10" maxlength="2" size="2">

<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number btn-plus p-l-10 p-r-10">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </button>
</span>
```

and also I have this jquery script :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on("click", ".btn-plus", function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            var quantity = $( this ).closest( ".quantity" ).val();
            alert (quantity);
        });
    });
</script>
```

theoretically, I can get value of input text once the `btn-plus` is clicked, but I still get `undefined` value as result.

how to get the input value of `.quantity` using `.closest`? thank you

Comment: `.quantity` is not parent of `.btn-plus`. You can find the `body` by `closest()`, after that... continue find `.quantity` by `find()`. `.quantity` is a friend of parent :D, just for fun.

Comment: The best solution is to get the closest parent as the parent of the span and input and select input child or get input as siblings of span. You have so many solution but input is not a prent of the span tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest) is used to find a matching ancestor element, in your case the `input` element is the previous sibling of the `button`s parent

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".btn-plus", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var quantity = $(this).parent().prev(".quantity").val();
    alert(quantity);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity" value="1" min="1" max="10" maxlength="2" size="2">

<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number btn-plus p-l-10 p-r-10">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".btn-plus", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var quantity = $(this).closest("span").prev().val();//use closest span and prev to get input
    alert(quantity);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control quantity" value="1" min="1" max="10" maxlength="2" size="2">

<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number btn-plus p-l-10 p-r-10">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">asdasdasdas</span>
</button>
</span>
```

Use `.closest()` span to get the parent span. Since input is before span use `.prev()`

Answer (score 0):

According to the JQuery website it appears as though the closest function acts similarly to the parents function in that it only looks at the ancestors of the element you are targeting.

https://api.jquery.com/closest/#entry-longdesc

As the input tag is not a parent of the button tag then the closest function will not find it.

Utilize a combination of parent and sibling or similar to target the input tag.